# Can you fly from Zagreb to the US without quarantining?

Tags: usa, air-travel, covid-19, quarantine

My friend is a British citizen who has been living in Zagreb, Croatia for a few months. He wants to fly to the US to see his family. Is there any way to do that without being quarantined on arrival, which would defeat the whole point of his visit?

I know that coming from Croatia does not mean you have to quarantine directly. The problem is how to get to the US without going via a country that will mean he has to quarantine when he gets to the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php) (-> USA), one doesn't have to quarantine if arriving from Croatia. So all you have to do is ensure that you fly to the US via some other country. Current options are Serbia and Turkey - both have a direct flight to the US and both don't require you to quarantine on arrival.

> 3. Passengers who have been in Austria, Belgium, Brazil, China (People's Rep.), Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Iran, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland or United Kingdom (excluding overseas territories outside of Europe) in the past 14 days but are exempt from the restriction to enter the USA, must self-quarantine for 14 days once they reach their final destination.

---

Full IATA information (note that if the passenger does a stopover and even just transit in some countries such as France, they won't even be allowed to enter the US (unless one is included in one of the exceptions, such as being a US citizen or LPR, in which one might have to self-quarantine):

> United States (Published 31.07.2020)
>
> 1. **Passengers who have transited or have been in Austria, Belgium, Brazil, China (People's Rep.), Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland,
>    France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Iran, Ireland (Rep.),
>    Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta,
>    Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain,
>    Sweden, Switzerland or in the United Kingdom (excluding overseas
>    territories outside of Europe), in the past 14 days are not allowed to
>    enter and transit.**
>
>    This does not apply to:
>
> - nationals and permanent residents of the USA;
> - spouses of nationals and of permanent residents of the USA;
> - parents/legal guardians of an unmarried and younger than 21 years national or permanent resident of the USA;
> - the unmarried and younger than 21 years brother or sister of a national or permanent resident of the USA, who is unmarried and
>   younger than 21 years;
> - the child/foster child/ward of a national or permanent resident of the USA;
> - passengers with the following visas: A-1, A-2, C-1, C-1/D, C-2, C-3, CR-1, CR-2, D, E-1 (as an employee of TECRO or TECO or the employee's
>   immediate family members), G-1, G-2, G-3, G-4, IR-1, IR-4, IH-4,
>   NATO-1 through NATO-4, or NATO-6 visa;
> - members of the U.S. Armed Forces, spouses, and children of members of the U.S. Armed Forces;
> - passengers with evidence of traveling at the invitation of the USA government for a purpose related to the containment/mitigation of the
>   Coronavirus (COVID-19);
> - passengers with documents issued by the U.S. Department of Homeland Security, U.S. Customs and Border Protection, or U.S. Department of
>   State indicating that the passenger is exempt from the restriction;
> - B1 crew crewmembers that are engaged in lightering, Outer Continental Shelf (OCS) activity, wind farm activity, private air/sea
>   crew and other similar crewmember actives;
> - students with an F-1 or M-1 visa and their F-2 and M-2 dependents, if they arrive from or have been in Ireland (Rep.), United Kingdom or
>   Schengen Member States in the past 14 days.
>
> 2. Passengers who have been in one of the countries listed in bullet number 1 in the past 14 days but are exempt from the restriction to
>    enter the USA, must arrive at one of the following airports: Atlanta
>    (ATL), Boston (BOS), Chicago (ORD), Dallas, (DFW), Detroit (DTW), Ft.
>    Lauderdale (FLL), Honolulu (HNL), Houston (IAH), Los Angeles (LAX),
>    Miami (MIA), New York (JFK or EWR), San Francisco (SFO), Seattle (SEA)
>    and Washington (IAD).
> 3. **Passengers who have been in Austria, Belgium, Brazil, China (People's Rep.), Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany,
>    Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Iran, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia,
>    Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway,
>    Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland or
>    United Kingdom (excluding overseas territories outside of Europe) in
>    the past 14 days but are exempt from the restriction to enter the USA,
>    must self-quarantine for 14 days once they reach their final
>    destination.**
> 4. Passengers arriving in Massachusetts must complete the "Massachusetts Travel Form" at
>    https://www.mass.gov/forms/massachusetts-travel-form . They are
>    subject to quarantine for 14 days.
> 5. Passports issued to nationals of Belarus which have expired between 30 April 2020 and 31 July 2020, are considered valid with an extension
>    of 3 months.

Comment: I think the answer depends on _how_ he gets from Croatia to RDU. Stopovers (not non-entry transits) may well change the traveler's obligation.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Good point. E.g. if they do a stopover and even just transit in France, they won't even be allowed to enter the US (unless they fit some exception, such as being a US citizen or LPR).

Comment: Yes. I think this was the point of the question. There are no direct flights from Zagreb.  I don't know if it's possible or not.

Comment: @Anush should be easy to find e.g. ZAG -> IST -> ICN -> US

Comment: Or BEG -> JFK..

Comment: These look like answers.  I would pick the cheapest that works

Comment: @Anush I think the question is about the necessity of quarantine, not about whether such flights exist.

Comment: Flying via Belgrade or Istanbul seems to answer the question.  However the OP may need to leave immediately as there is a strong risk Croatia will be added to the quarantine list.

Comment: Worth noting that "arriving in Massachusetts" does not include transiting in Boston, but does include traveling to MA after being abroad or elsewhere in the US, except for (as of 8/21) CT, ME, NH, NJ, NY, or VT within the last 14 days .